# How to send Customized User-Agent and Referrer with cCurl?

Tags: php, curl

I would like to receive mobile version of page when using ccurl. Is there a way to send customized user-agent and customized referrer when making ccurl call ? If the answer is yes how ?

```
function get_data($url) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}

$page="http://www.somesite.com";
$input = get_data($page);
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'SomeReferrer');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'SomeUA');
```

Comment: Thanks . Can we do same thing with getJson too ? How ?